# Getting exception using ProviderFactory to create a SQLite connection

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite, dbproviderfactories

I am trying to use the ProviderFactory.CreateConnection() to obtain a SQLite connection. I am getting a System.ArgumentException with the following message:

**"Keyword not supported: 'datetimeformat'."**

The connection string is:

```
@"data source=d:\db\Test.db3;Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=10;datetimeformat=Ticks"
```

In the app.config file I have:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
    <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
       support="3F" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
         type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

The connection string works when I instantiate a SQLiteConnection instance. It fails using the ProviderFactory. Any suggestions on how I can resolve this?

Comment: "ProviderFactory" is my own property accessor to DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("...")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out, that I forgot to execute the following line of code:

```
DbProviderFactory providerFactory =
    DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");
```

And the ensuing code worked then as expected without exception:

```
IDbConnection conn = providerFactory.CreateConnection();
```

Comment: Do you mean DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SQLite")?

Comment: It connects to the internal `SQLServer` database and thinks it works with `sqlite` :D